# PYTHON: AttributeError - calling function in a member function of a class

Tags: python, function, class

I'm having trouble with classes in Python 2.7:

First, I really do not know how to use the __init__ properly, so I have just used a dummy call to `print`. What should I do instead?

Second, I would like the member function `readAnyFormat` to call a few functions (later I will create a kind of case statement). My attempt produced an `AttributeError`. How do I do this correctly?

My class is as follows:

```
class ArangeData:

        def __init__(
                    self):

            print ' '

        def readAnyFormat(
                    self,
                    config = True,
                    mypath='text.txt',
                    data_format='ASCII',
                    data_shape='shaped'):

            #Here the function should be called:'
            #NOT WORKING: 
            #AttributeError: ArangeData instance has no attribute 'readASCII'
            if data_format=='HDF5':
                readHDF5()
            elif data_format=='ASCII':
                readASCII()


            def readASCII():
                'doing stuff in here'

            def readHDF5():
                'doing other stuff in here, which is not the business of readASCII'

        def otherMemberFunction(self):
            'do not care what they are doing above!'
```

Comment: Please read the [Python Style Guide (PEP8)](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/). It's very good and will make your code much easier to read. You'll thank me later!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- You should move the definition of `readASCII` and `readHDF5` so they are above the two `if` statements.
- You don't need to have the dummy `print` statement in `__init__`. If you have nothing to initialize you can simply use `pass`, or better yet as @chepner commented don't even define `__init__`.

Comment: In general, it's probably better to just not define `__init__` at all; this lets the parent class's `__init__` be used if you have nothing to add.

Comment: Also since this is Python 2.7 OP is (probably inadvertently) using old-style classes.